# Cannot start rails server, I get an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. So, I'd got this error before, and I reinstalled rails and ruby and installed them again, but I still get it.
The error is:

```
/home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /home/X/Documents/Appw/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/X/Documents/Appw/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/X/Documents/Appw/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.1/bin/spring:51:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/X/Documents/Appw/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /home/X/Documents/Appw/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I tried updating the uglifier gem, but nothing happened.

Comment: Show your Gemfile. Were there any errors during bundling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have't installed nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Should work !!!

Comment: @Buno:  too Glad It helps :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't have nodejs installed. After I've installed it, everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

What is you gemfile/gem list?

Actually having meteor installed doesn't count as having nodejs installed. nodejs is required for uglifier package, so simple: `yum install nodejs` resolves the issue.

Comment: Why do you think he has meteor installed, but not node.js?